# Show nearby restaurants in the google map integrated within flutter application

Tags: flutter, dart, google-places-api

I am developing a flutter application where I have already integrated google map and I am able to get the current location of the user as well. I want to show the nearby restaurants in the map and want them to be marked on the map. Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use google map markers or you can use my our package on the pub.dev which gives you
opportunity to add any widget to any location on the map.

https://pub.dev/packages/decorated_google_maps_flutter

Comment: In here they have predefined locations, I don't want that. I want to dynamically show the restaurants near or within the specified radius

Comment: You can fetch restaurant locations from api or something and iterate through that and create markers or widgets for that locations

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Places API by enabling it inside API library in your Google Cloud project.

[Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places/)

This will enable you to find the nearest places of interest e.g restaurants. etc and get the location in the response data.

Once you get the latitude/Longitude from the response, parse accordingly and draw a marker on those places over Google Map.